# HTML Flexbox Gallery

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a responsive 9×9 gallery, with an overlay (trying with a div with color and text), when hovering. Like this: [Slide in Overlay from the Bottom](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_css_image_overlay_slidebottom).

But, I can't overlay the  exactly over the images. Now, I am trying it with Flexbox, but I don't get it either.

The HTML with the images is looking like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">

    <div class="cell">
      <div class="overlay"></div><img src="img/Portrait.jpg" alt="Project 01" class="image left"></div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="overlay"></div><img src="img/Portrait.jpg" alt="Project 02" class="image middle"></div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="overlay"></div><img src="img/Portrait.jpg" alt="Project 03" class="image right"></div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="overlay"></div><img src="img/Portrait.jpg" alt="Project 04" class="image left"></div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="overlay"></div><img src="img/Portrait.jpg" alt="Project 05" class="image middle"></div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="overlay"></div><img src="img/Portrait.jpg" alt="Project 06" class="image right"></div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="overlay"></div><img src="img/Portrait.jpg" alt="Project 07" class="image left"></div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="overlay"></div><img src="img/Portrait.jpg" alt="Project 08" class="image middle"></div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="overlay"></div><img src="img/Portrait.jpg" alt="Project 09" class="image right"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS i am currently on like this:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

img {
  padding: 2px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cell {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.overlay {
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Media Queries:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .cell {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .cell {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
  }
}
```

Currently, it looks like this with over 1000px:

[image: Current]

Red is the Flexboxgrid (original position) `class="grid"`. Violet are the pictures (which currently lost the position) and the black (opacity 0.5) matches exact over the red grid.

How do I match the overlay-divs exactly with the same padding of 2px over the images?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it uses **absolute URLs** for images, providing a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea would be to abolutely position the overlay over the image relative to `.cell`, then use `translateY()` to move it outside of the `.cell` and transition `translateY()` on `.cell:hover`

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

img {
  padding: 2px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform .5s;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cell:hover .overlay {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="overlay">text</div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png" alt="Project 01" class="image left">
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="overlay">text</div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png" alt="Project 01" class="image left">
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="overlay">text</div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png" alt="Project 01" class="image left">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't got it with position and overflow.